# Use different MySQL database based on condition

Tags: mysql, database, variables, select

I have two almost identical databases but with different names. I want to create a universal SQL for both. So get the database name and then use the table from that. Can I do that?

Code:

```
SELECT @db := DATABASE();

SELECT
  *
FROM
  @db.table1 t1
INNER JOIN
  @db.table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.table2_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work for you:

```
SELECT @db := DATABASE();
select @stmt:= concat('SELECT
  *
FROM `', @db, '`.table1 t1
INNER JOIN
  `', @db, '`.table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.table2_id');
Prepare stmt FROM @stmt;
execute stmt;
```

Comment: @DenesCsesznegi, thanks for accepting the answer! :)

Comment: That's the least I could do. :)